# Docker executable not found

Tags: docker, g++, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize a `cpp` application and after i build the image in docker and run it i get an error.
**Error**:
 `/bin/sh: 1:home/simple/Main: not found`

**main.cpp**

```
 #include<iostream>

 int main(){
 std::cout<<"Hellow World";
 return 0;
 }
```

I compile this with : `g++ -o Main main.cpp`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir -p /home/simple
COPY . /home/simple
CMD home/simple/Main
```

**Docker commands**

`docker build -t myapp .`
 `docker run myapp`

**P.S**  I have followed this guide :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kejsVBoP4kE

 How can it not find the `Main.exe` since it is in the same folder with the `Dockerfile`?
Could it be that when using `Copy . /home/simple` it copies only `1/2` of the file(s) ?

Comment: If should not be `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "./home/simple/Main" ]`? And I think you should give the "x" permission to it first.

Comment: none of that is necessary. and Main will already be executable. the only thing that's missing is #include<iostream> but i think that's just an oversight while posting the question, because otherwise compilation would fail. Really strange, i am trying to reproduce the error, but it works for me...

Comment: Indeed,the include is present.This is why i am curious.It just says the executable is not there and i have no idea why.

Comment: Either the binary isn't in `$PWD/home/simple` (I don't remember off hand what the default WORKDIR is), or you're not compiling on a compatible Linux host, or you need a shared library that isn't in the container (a little unlikely with that command line).

Comment: Well  the `binary` is in the same folder with the `Dockerfile`.So if i set `COPY . /home/simple` it can't copy  `1/2` files could it? And i used `FROM ubuntu:latest` as OS.